# How to convert a string like "3hr 4min 5sec" to seconds in java?

Tags: java

Is there any library function in JAVA that takes a string input like **3hr 4min 5sec** and convert it to a seconds (integer value) ?

Example : if input is 1 hr 5 sec, then answer should be 3605.

Thanks.

Comment: I think no. But it is quite simple to write such a method. So simply take a try.

Comment: I guess/hope that it's an input that you're not controlling?

Comment: Are there spaces or no? You'd probably have to manually parse it.

Comment: @Compass : Yes, there are spaces.

Comment: I suggest you at least try doing this one alone :) TIP: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html It's really not that hard.

Comment: @Simon : Every second I am getting a new input from some API calls. So, I am not controlling input in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse it manually:

```
String input = "3hr 4min 5sec";
int sum = 0;
String[] arr = input.split(" ");
for(String s:arr){
  if(s.endsWith("hr"))
    sum += Integer.valueOf(s.substring(0, s.indexOf("hr"))) * 3600;
  if(s.endsWith("min"))
    sum += Integer.valueOf(s.substring(0, s.indexOf("min"))) * 60;
  if(s.endsWith("sec"))
    sum += Integer.valueOf(s.substring(0, s.indexOf("sec")));
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

prints `11045`. This also allows that one of the elements (e.g. minutes) are missing.

EDIT: replaced the regex approach with string splitting to allow elements to be missing

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although, I have written one code snippet but your code seems to be more clear and precise. Thanks again !

Comment: @user122345656 i don't really like it but it's very straightforward. Hope it helps!